# Yii2 basepath URL are different in linux and windows?

Tags: php, ubuntu, yii2, image-uploading

To upload image in a a directory i have used

```
\Yii::$app->basePath.Yii::$app->params['product_thumb_image_path']
```

Its return c://xampp/...folder and uploading file correctly but in Ubuntu the URL convert into /var/www/html/....\folder. The front and backslash is different in both OS. Its not working in Ubuntu. Am i missing something? I have faced this situation first time. Please help on this issue.

Comment: it's because the Directory saperator in windows and linux. In windows DS is \ and in linux DS is /

Comment: what value `Yii::$app->params['product_thumb_image_path']` does have?

Comment: \web\uploads\product\ but now i changed into /web/uploads/product/ and its working on both OS.

Comment: It's better work with aliases, for example, to get the path: `getAlias("@web") . '/' . getAlias("@product_thumb_image_path")`

Answer (score 1):

Change the `\` in `Yii::$app->params['product_thumb_image_path']` to `/`. From the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php)

> On Windows, both slash (/) and backslash () are used as directory separator character. In other environments, it is the forward slash (/).